# Form results not coming through on IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, validation

We are getting results just fine in all browsers EXCEPT IE with the following [example form](http://www.yaskawa.com/attachments/surveys/survey.html?RF=sample&RL=lastname&Q1_1=%2425000.00).

The form looks like it goes through fine in IE (says submitted successfully), but the results never come through. I've tried removing all tables in the code (separately) to see if that would help and it didn't. I do not know much about Javascript, but am trying to solve this problem. Any ideas?  The javaScript from the validation (`summation_check_final.js`) is below:

```
function validate_input(value,string){
var error = 0;
var reg = /^[\s\d]*$/
if(!reg.test(value)){
        alert(string + ' has to be blank or a number');
        error = 1;
}
return error;
}

function summation(){
var total = 0;
var automotive = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_259_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(automotive);
var printing = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_269_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(printing);
var hvac = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_260_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(hvac); 
var refrigeration = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_270_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(refrigeration);        
var conveyors = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_261_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(conveyors);        
var robotics = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_271_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(robotics);        
var cranes = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_262_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(cranes);        
var rubber = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_272_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(rubber);        
var elevators = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_263_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(elevators);        
var semiconductor = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_273_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(semiconductor);        
var food = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_264_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(food);        
var shipbuilding = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_274_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(shipbuilding);        
var tools = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_265_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(tools);        
var textiles = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_275_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(textiles);        
var mining = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_266_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(mining);        
var woodworking = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_276_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(woodworking);        
var packaging = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_267_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(packaging);        
var other = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_277_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(other);        
var paper = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_268_SGVAL_1]').val();
total += Number(paper);
return total;
}

function update_total(){
 var total = summation()
 var num_str = total.toString();
 $("#total").text(num_str);
 return total;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var error = 0;
    var automotive = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_259_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var printing = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_269_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var hvac = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_260_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var refrigeration = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_270_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var conveyors = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_261_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var robotics = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_271_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var cranes = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_262_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var rubber = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_272_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var elevators = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_263_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var semiconductor = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_273_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var food = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_264_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var shipbuilding = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_274_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var tools = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_265_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var textiles = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_275_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var mining = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_266_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var woodworking = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_276_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var packaging = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_267_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var other = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_277_SGVAL_1]').val();
    var paper = $('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_268_SGVAL_1]').val();

    error = validate_input(automotive,'Automotive');
    error = validate_input(printing,'Printing');
    error = validate_input(hvac,'Commercial HVAC');
    error = validate_input(refrigeration,'Refrigeration');
    error = validate_input(conveyors,'Conveyors');
    error = validate_input(robotics,'Robotics:');
    error = validate_input(cranes,'Cranes & Hoist');
    error = validate_input(rubber,'Rubber & Plastics');
    error = validate_input(elevators,'Elevators & Escalators');
    error = validate_input(semiconductor,'Semiconductor');
    error = validate_input(food,'Food, Beverage & Tobacco');
    error = validate_input(shipbuilding,'Shipbuilding & Marine');
    error = validate_input(tools,'Machine Tools');
    error = validate_input(textiles,'Textiles');
    error = validate_input(mining,'Mining');
    error = validate_input(woodworking,'Woodworking');
    error = validate_input(packaging,'Packaging & Labeling');
    error = validate_input(other,'Other Discrete Sectors');
    error = validate_input(paper,'Paper & Paperboard');

    var total = update_total();

    var rf = $('input[name=RF]').val();
    if(rf == ''){
        alert('First Name is a required field');
        error = 8;
    }

    var rl = $('input[name=RL]').val();
    if(rl == ''){
        alert('Last Name is a required field');
        error = 8;
    }

    if (total == 100 && error == 0){         
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.surveygold.com/cgi-bin/WebSurveyResponseProcess.asp", 
            data: $('#SGWebForm').serialize(),
            success: alert('Submit successful')
        });
    }
    if(total != 100){
        alert('The total of the percentages has to be 100');
    }
});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_259_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_269_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_260_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_270_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_261_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_271_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_262_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_272_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_263_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_273_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_264_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_274_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_265_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_275_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_266_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_276_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_267_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_277_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});
$('input[name=Q28_SGVAL_268_SGVAL_1]').change(function(){update_total();});     
});
```

Comment: You are not able to get response because the ajax request is generating an error.
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.surveygold.com/cgi-bin/WebSurveyResponseProcess.asp. Origin http://www.yaskawa.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: have you heard of Don't Repeat Yourself? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: agreed with @mrhobo .... that code is in urgent need of a tidy up.